# Is the map to the identity element a homomorphism?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

Assuming we have a homomorphism from $G\rightarrow G$, defined as $f(A) = e_G$. Is that a valid homomorphism? For example, $\mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, defined as $f(A) = I$, where $A$ is a matrix in $\mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{R})$.

Am I correct to say that $\ker(f) = G$? Or in my specific example $\ker(f) = \mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{R})$? If not, is there a way to construct a homomorphism from a group to itself such that $\ker(f) = G$, or in the specific example I suggested, $\ker(f) = \mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{R})$?

Thanks!

Comment: $f(A)=e_G$ is indeed a valid homomorphism.

Comment: Thank you. Am I correct in what I assumed the kernel to be, that is all of the group since everything is being mapped to the identity element?

Comment: Yes, this is correct aswell,

Comment: Yes, the kernel is the entire domain.  This is the trivial homomorphism

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check!